# How to react on something matching a certain pattern from a an event stream using Reactive Extensions?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

Suppose you want to react when some word in a stream of characters in a text box matches a certain pattern, could this be done using Rx? So if the initial source looks like this:

```
var charStream = Observable.
    FromEventPattern<KeyPressEventArgs>(textBox, "KeyPress");
```

To just create an observable word stream from this I imagine you could subscribe to `charStream` and post `OnNext` when ever you see a word separator:

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
var res = charStream.Subscribe(keyCharEv => {
    if (!Char.IsWordSeparator(keyCharEv.EventArgs.KeyChar))
        word.Append(keyCharEv.EventArgs.KeyChar);
    else
    {
        wordObservable.OnNext(word.ToString());
        word.Clear();
    }
});
```

The observer of `wordObservable` could then filter out the words matching the pattern. However, the above could easily be accomplished with the old-fashioned event mechanism in .NET and it also doesn't take in to account that some text can be copied in at any place in the text box or that enter is pressed in a middle of an already written word etc.

My question is, is Rx a bad fit for this kind of problem or are there some things in Rx that could be applied here (I do realize that there are other ways of solving this than by using Rx, I'm only trying to understand the workings of Rx here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it could be done using the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609), but I believe you're approaching the problem from the wrong perspective.

You are viewing the [`KeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) as the way to obtain a stream of characters.  That's incorrect, the observable of the `KeyPress` events is just that, key presses.  Yes, they correspond to characters in words *at times*, but as you mentioned, there are key presses that have nothing to do with characters in words, but other operations.

That said, you shouldn't be subscribing to the `KeyPress` event, but rather, the [`TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx).  Then, your [`IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx%27) should return an array of string instances which correspond to the words.

In other words, instead of streaming the key presses and trying to figure out what words are in the box in an additive way, take the *entire* text in the box and make the change of the words in the box the thing you observe on:

```
var textChanges = Observable.
    FromEventPattern<EventHandler>(textBox, "TextChanged");

// Create an observable that contains the splits.
IObservable<IList<string>> observableWordChanges = textChanges.Select(e => { 
    // Get the text.
    string text = (e.Sender as TextBox).Text;

    // The current word.
    var word = new StringBuilder();

    // The list of words.
    IList<string> words = new List<string>();

    // Parse.
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (!Char.IsWordSeparator(c))
            word.Append(c);
        else
        {
            // Add to the words.
            words.Add(word.ToString());

            // Clear the builder.
            word.Clear();
        }
    }

    // Return the words.
    return words;
});
```

From here, you subscribe to the changes in the words as a set, not just characters in the `TextBox`.

Granted, it's a little more computationally intensive, but the other alternative is to capture all the different states that *any* key press would have, and you might not get all of them correct.

This way, you'll get the words in the box every time and can compare against previous words correctly.

As to whether or not there is any value doing this as opposed to just using raw events, I would say yes.  Two of the great benefits of using the Reactive extensions are:

- Encapsulation of logic for processing of event streams.
- Handles multiple subscriptions to the same event stream.

In this particular example, you benefit from both.

You could have done the word set parsing by hooking to the `TextChanged` event, but you would have then had to have stored *some* sort of state in the same structure that the event handler (in this case, the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)) is declared in.  With the Reactive extensions, that would have not been required (it's contained in the enclosure).

Additionally, if you wanted to attach some additional behavior to the processing of a stream of events, you would have to have two calls in one event handler, or multiple event handlers.  With the Reactive extensions, because of the better encapsulation of state, it's easier to add multiple handlers for the stream of events to the same event, at whatever time you choose (depending on when you subscribe).

Comment: Thanks! But does Rx brings any added value to this compared to just listening to the TextChanged event (apart from that the Rx-solution isn't blocking)?

Comment: @Christain: I've updated my response to address benefits over event handlers, as it would have been too long to place in the comments.

Comment: Since events are multi-cast delegates, it's easy to attach multiple handlers. The real benefit with Rx is the ability to coordinate multiple event streams. If you're just dealing with the single keypress stream, standard events may be sufficient. Rx also shines when trying to pass the observables around to other listeners (through Dependency Injection for example) and resource cleanup through the IDisposable that's returned from the subscription.

Comment: @casperOne: your code example generates a new set of words (marble) for each key press even when there's no change compared to the previous set. Can you fix this inside the closure or do you need to apply a filter on the observableWordChanges?

Comment: @Christian: That's entirely the point, the `KeyPress` event is ill-suited for trying to do change detection between the current list of known words and what is actually in the `TextBox`; too many cases would have to be duplicated in order to get only the changes.  That said, you'd have to keep track of the previous set externally (where you subscribe to the observable) and do the change comparison there.  You could do it inside with closures, but it still requires state to be saved *somewhere*.

Comment: @casperOne: thanks again! I'm starting to see the light (I think) :). I guess you could apply DistinctUntilChanged() on the observable word sequence in order to get OnNext calls only when the set of words has changed.

Comment: @Christian: Yes, you could use `DistinctUntilChanged`, but you run the risk of not getting notified when there is an undo.  Let's say the initial text was copied into the `TextBox`, that's one `OnNext` called with the array of words.  Then the word "hello" is added (it wasn't there before).  Another `OnNext` call with "hello" added.  Then "hello" is removed.  `OnNext` wouldn't be called here because the set of words without "hello" has already been observed and is not distinct anymore.  That might be the behavior one wants, but be sure that's the case.

Comment: @casperOne: the case you're describing applies to the Distinct method right? My understanding is that DistinctUntilChanged accepts non-distinct observations as long as they're not contigous.

Comment: @Christian: If that's the case, then yes, `DistinctUntilChanged` will perform the filtering you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fine problem for Rx, as others have demonstrated how. One of the benefits that Rx provides is composition and separation of event processing logic from event handling logic.

With event handlers, this is... difficult. But with Rx, you can have an `IObservable<string> words` which can be

- Replaced by an alternate implementation for testing
- Composed with additional filters and projections, independent of the source of the words
- Be subscribed to, just like a normal event

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly then you want to generate stream of words from the text box whenever the text box value is changed.

This can be done easily in Rx using:

```
Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged")
    .Select(e => ((TextBox)e.Sender).Text)
    .SelectMany(t => t.Split(" ".ToCharArray()).Where(
        a => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)))
```

Then you can subscribe to the above observable to react to words coming from Text box.

You can do this in normal event handling but the power of Rx comes into play when you need to compose multiple event streams and do complex processing like filter, buffer etc.

Comment: Tried your example after changing FromEvent to FromEventPattern for it to compile, but it didn't work as intended.